# How do you make swing calls in a catch block

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, try-catch, event-dispatch-thread

In the catch block I want to display a error message to textArea to display the error happening.

Comment: The same way you'd display an error message outside a catch block. There's nothing different going on.

Comment: I'm not on the event dispatch thread in the catch block

Comment: If the `try` is on the EDT then so will the `catch`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are not on the EDT, you can use [`SwingUtilities#invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to safely perform your action on the EDT.

Answer (score 2):

A catch block does not limit the methods you can call in any way : it is only different from the try block above it in that it is not, as is, in a exception handling scope.

Thus, you can

1) enclose the call to Any exception throwing gui elements, in the catch block, inside another try/catch

Or simpler

2) Simply use a component like JoptionPane which will safely launch an exception-less dialog box.